# load twig expression from database without template_from_string

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my database I store e-mail templates with personalized subject lines like `Dear {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }}, thank you for registration!`.

The users of the system should be able to write new subject lines containing different variables like `firstname`, `lastname`, `salutation` etc., which are also stored in the database.

I don't want to solve this issue by using the `template_from_string` function as explained in other questions.

This is the controller I use to send the email:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Lead;
use AppBundle\Form\LeadType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{url}")
     */
    public function submitFormAction($url, Request $request)
    {
        $frontend_vars = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Publisher')
            ->findOneByUrl($url);

        if($frontend_vars == null) {
            return $this->render('frontend/register_error.html.twig');
        }

        $lead = new Lead();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\LeadType', $lead, array(
            'frontend_vars' => $frontend_vars
        ));
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // Generate Unique User Hash
            // $lead->setUniqueUserHash() = 'julius';

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($lead);
            $em->flush();

            // Send Mail
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($frontend_vars->getMailsubject())
                ->setFrom('$frontend_vars->getMailfrom()')
                ->setTo('me@mycompany.com')
                ->setBody($frontend_vars->getMailcontent()),
                    'text/html'
                );

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('lastPage', array('url' => $frontend_vars->getUrl()));
        }

        return $this->render('frontend/register.html.twig', array(
            'content' => $frontend_vars,
            'logos' => $logopath,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

I don't have any twig files for creating the email as they're generated by sonata admin bundle `function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) { ... }`

So in the form fields generated by the the sonata admin bundle the user should enter subject, from address and content like that:

> "Dear {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }}, thank you for registering!"

Comment: Please show some example code that you have tried, including controller and full twig file.

Comment: Just added my code.